# Boost graph library: Get edge_descriptor or access edge by index of type int

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I'm a BGL newbie with a (possibly) easy question: I have a directed graph and use bundled properties for edges, one of them being an index of type int. Knowing a unique index, I would like to get the corresponding edge_descriptor of that edge in order to perform operations on it. The following example summarizes my problem:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

struct EdgeProperties {
    EdgeProperties(): distance(10), time_limit(5) {};
    int index;
    int distance;
    int time_limit;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeProperties> Graph;

int main() {

    Graph graph;

    EdgeProperties edge_prop1, edge_prop2, edge_prop3, edge_prop4;

    // Define edge properties
    edge_prop1.index = 0;
    edge_prop2.index = 1;
    edge_prop3.index = 2;
    edge_prop4.index = 3;

    // Add edges to graph
    boost::add_edge(0, 1, edge_prop1, graph);
    boost::add_edge(0, 2, edge_prop2, graph);
    boost::add_edge(1, 3, edge_prop3, graph);
    boost::add_edge(2, 3, edge_prop4, graph);

    // Get vertex_descriptor from an (int) index:
    int vertex_index = 2;
    boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor v = boost::vertex(vertex_index, graph);

    // I would like to get an edge_descriptor from an (int) index property:
    // The following DOES NOT work:
    boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor e = boost::edge(edge_prop1.index, graph);
}
```

I read about property maps as well, but could not find a solution my problem. I would prefer [bundled properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) over internal properties.
Is there a way of assigning unique int type indices via a bundle property to edges and access edges through these int type values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think `boost::graph` is of immediate help here.

First, there is no mechanism to find an edge (or vertex, for that matter), based on a field of an edge property - BGL keeps any such mapping, and the 'index' field you have is entirely for your purposes.

Second, there is the `boost::edges` function that returns an iterator range for all edges of the graph. I though that you could pass vecS as edge container type to adjacency_list template, and then look inside this range, but per http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/EdgeListGraph.html the iterators are only required to be multi-pass input iterators, and the implementation does exactly that -- even with vecS as edge type, you can't do random access.

Therefore, it seems that the only way to accomplish what you want is to keep your own `unodered_map` from index to edge descriptor.